Symfony app in docker swarm mode with multiple replicas, session problem?
I have a problem with Symfony 7 app on production with docker swarm and nginx acting as reverse proxy.
With 1 replica everything works just fine, but with 2 or more replicas my app starts but I can't log into it. The app uses a standard Symfony approach with login form (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#form-login).
The application image is build from php:8.2-apache and Apache is of course the running web server inside app containers.
Here is my config (I've omitted irrelevant stuff):
swarm_stack.yml
services:
    nginx:
        image: ghcr.io/mygh/nginx:docker
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"

    backend_app:
        image: ghcr.io/mygh/backend:docker
        deploy:
            replicas: 2
        ports:
            - "8000:80"

nginx.conf
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name  backendapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_app:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

I'm thinking, since the login in fails, there might be a problem with sharing session between replicas / worker nodes? Or maybe the problem is in the approach itself? This is my first attempt to configure the stack in that way.

"Since the login in fails" - what exactly does that mean? Does your log contain any information about this? How did you configure a shared session (where all containers would have the same session information, either through a shared directory or any session provider), or a sticky session (where a user would get tied to a specific container and not switch between them during following requests)?

@NicoHaase actually I haven't configured any session sharing mechanism, that's probably the problem.. But I don't know how to approach this yet. I've read that nginx has sticky sessions but it's paid tho. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#enabling-session-persistence I see that I would have to create duplicate services (on different ports) and config load balancing in nginx config, not use docker swarm to create replicas. Am I right?

If sticky sessions in nginx is not an option, it might be easier to use a different session storage in Symfony, as documented in https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#store-sessions-in-a-database - where even the first paragraph contains "If your application is served by multiple servers(...)"

@NicoHaase thanks for pointing that out, I totally forgot about it!

Ok, it was a session sharing problem. Since Nginx Plus (and its sticky session) is a 'little' too expensive for my application I went for configuring Symfony to store sessions in Redis. Works like a charm.
Again thanks to @NicoHaase for pointing that out.
